# com/jniwrapper/win32/ie/WebBrowser class not found

Tags: java

com/jniwrapper/win32/ie/WebBrowser class not found.

From where can I download jniWrapper library.

I have downloaded it from teamdev.com and it has win32 package also but this win32 package doesn't contain ie package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The win32/ie package can be found in the JExplorer librairie ,  look [there](http://www.teamdev.com/jexplorer/documentation/)